# How to create a function that allows my to make a 2d tuple list with this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

```
 df1=a[['genres','imdb_score']]
 df1


        genres                      imdb_score
0   Action|Adventure|Fantasy|Sci-Fi     7.9
1   Action|Adventure|Fantasy            7.1
2   Action|Adventure|Thriller           6.8
3   Action|Thriller                     8.5
4   Documentary                         7.1
    ... ... ...
5038  Comedy|Drama                      7.7
5039  Crime|Drama|Mystery|Thriller      7.5
5040  Drama|Horror|Thriller             6.3
5041  Comedy|Drama|Romance              6.3
5042  Documentary                       6.6

 def tuples(p):
list=[]
t=df1.genres.str.split('|').join(df1['imdb_score'])
list.append(t)
return list
```

This is what I did and it doesn't work and I want to get the thing below.Thank you very much.

```
       [('Action', 7.9) ('Adventure', 7.9) ('Fantasy', 7.9) ('Sci-Fi', 7.9)]
```

Comment: Does this work for you? `[(g, s) for G, s in zip(df.genres, df.imdb_score) for g in G.split('|')]`

Comment: Or maybe `[[(g, s) for g in G.split('|')] for G, s in zip(df.genres, df.imdb_score)]`

Comment: Yes it does how would I apply to this to individual rows?. For instance the first one I tried print(tuples.iloc([0,:],df1)) as my input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that does what you want:

```
def get_columns_as_tuples(df, indices):
    return [[(genre, score) for 
              genre in genres.split('|')] for 
              _, (genres, score) in df.loc[indices].iterrows()]
```

It returns a list of lists because it allows for you to select which indices to get the data from.

Examples:

```
# get data from rows whose index is in [0]
>>> get_columns_as_tuples(df=df, indices=[0])
[[('Action', 7.9), ('Adventure', 7.9), ('Fantasy', 7.9), ('Sci-Fi', 7.9)]]

# get data from rows whose index is in [0, 1]
>>> get_columns_as_tuples(df=df, indices=[0, 1])
[[('Action', 7.9), ('Adventure', 7.9), ('Fantasy', 7.9), ('Sci-Fi', 7.9)],
 [('Action', 7.1), ('Adventure', 7.1), ('Fantasy', 7.1)]]
```

Comment: What to do if I want to apply it to all the rows?

Comment: simply pass `df.index` as the second argument.

Comment: Anyway I could the .apply method for this. Sorry I'm new to python and to find out as many ways as possible of doing this.